# Double slit diffraction derivation

Tags: optics, double-slit-experiment

The task is to derive the intensity pattern of a double slit diffraction, where light travels along the $z$-axis, the point of interest lies on the $x$-$z$ plane, the slits are wide (in $z$-direction) and infinite in extent in the $y$-direction.
But how can this be derived by Fraunhofer diffraction, when one of the assumptions of Fraunhofer is, that the aperture is much smaller in size than the distance of aperture-POI?
Because when using the Fraunhofer formula:

$$U(P)\propto e^{ik(s_0+d_0)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t(x,y) e^{-ik(Xx+Yy)}\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$

where $d_0, s_0$ are the distances of the source (here infinity) to the aperture and the distance of aperture - POI, and $X = x_s/s_0 + x_p/d_0$ and $Y = y_s/s_0 + y_p/d_0$. The problem comes from $y_p = 0, y_s=0 \implies Y=0$, so an integration over $y$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ would diverge. How can I deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, an infinite slit would give infinite illumination.

To see what happen, we can give the slit a finite height $H$ and integrate from $-H / 2$ to $H / 2$:

$s=\int\limits_{-H/2}^{H/2}{{{e}^{jkYy}}dy=}H\text{sinc}\left( \frac{kAY}{2} \right)$ with the sinc function defined by $\text{sinc}(u)=\frac{\sin (u)}{u}$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function

The factor $H$ must be grouped in the intensity in the center of the figure: $I=cst{{s}^{2}}=\underbrace{cst{{H}^{2}}}_{I\text{center}}\text{sin}{{\text{c}}^{\text{2}}}\left( \frac{kHY}{2} \right)={{I}_{\text{center}}}\text{sin}{{\text{c}}^{\text{2}}}\left( \frac{kHY}{2} \right)$

You then compare the illumination in the center and the illumination at any point on the screen. We have the first zero minimum:  $\frac{kHY}{2}=\pm \pi $ give $Y=\pm \frac{2\pi }{kH}=\pm \frac{\lambda }{H}$ decrease when $H$ increase.

Mathematically, at the limit of $H$ infinite, we have a Dirac: infinite amplitude over a null width : $\underset{H\to +\infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,H\text{sinc}(Hx)=\delta (x)$

Sorry for my English !

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but how can I deal with this specific type of problem, where the width of the slit in y-direction is infinite?
If it helps, the solution is given by
$I(\theta) = I_0 \left( \dfrac{sin(ka/2 sin(\theta)}{ka/2 sin(\theta)} \right)^2 cos^2(kd/2 sin(\theta)$
where $\theta$ indicates the direction of the light relative to the z-axis in the x-y plane, a is the slit-width and d is the distance of the two slits.

Comment: @Samuel such a slit does not fit in the lab. Infinite means large enough so that no significant diffraction occurs. In practice the slit is of finite length in y, so that the integration does not diverge. By the way, $\theta$ is the angle in the xz plane, independent of y.

Comment: @my2cts But when I strictly apply Huygen's law, then why do I not have to integrate over y? I mean every point $S'=(a, y, 0)$ is acting as a source, right?

Answer (score 0):

T(x, y) is t(x) for an infinite slit in the y direction. You can drop the integration over y since the problem is independent of y.

Comment: I feel this could use a bit more details than what's written here.

Comment: I've done that, and got this result:
$U(P) \propto \int_{(d-a)/2}^{(d+a)/2}exp(-ikXx) dx +  \int_{-(d+a)/2}^{-(d-a)/2}exp(-ikXx) dx = [...] = \dfrac{i}{kX}(2isin(kX (d-a)/2) - 2isin(kX (d-a)/2)$ 

and for the intensity:
$I(P) = |U(P)|^2 = |\dfrac{4}{kX}cos(kXd/2)sin(kXa/2)|^2$ which is almost the result I need. But as you can see in my comment above, in the denominator there should be a $ka/2sin(\theta)$, but $X=tan(\theta)$

Comment: yet the integration as written clearly depends on $y$...

Comment: @ZeroTheHero no it does not. T(x, y) is t(x) for an infinite slit in the y direction.

Comment: @my2cts that should be part of your answer...

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I extended my answer. It was a bit short anyway...